# Sparse vector to dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have sparsevector in pyspark which looks like this

```
SparseVector(5,{1:5,2:3,3:5,4:3,5:2})
```

How can I convert it to pandas dataframe with two columns which loks like this

```
ID VALUE
1   5
2   3
3   5
4   3
5   2
```

I tried sparsevector.zipWithIndex() but it did not work

Comment: Can you update your question with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example array is malformed, as you've specified 5 levels so there can not be an index 5. After you fix that issue, you can simply call [`toArray()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector.toArray) which will return a `numpy.ndarray`. Just pass that into the constructor for a `pandas.DataFrame`.

```python
from  pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector  # code works the same
#from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector     # code works the same

import pandas as pd

a = SparseVector(5,{0:5,1:3,2:5,3:3,4:2})  # note the index starts at 0
df = pd.DataFrame(a.toArray())
print(df)
#     0
#0  5.0
#1  3.0
#2  5.0
#3  3.0
#4  2.0
```

The code works the same whether you're working with `pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector` or `pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector`.